# PHP connect to SQL server with a windows account

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, management-studio-express

I am trying to connect to a SQL server database with a windows account. In sql managment studio, I can open the database with this account but not with my php application. This user is not a sql user, but he have the right on the SQL database.

I tried with a sql user and it works with my php application.

Is it possible to use my windows account from the php application, and not a specifique sql user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sqlsrv_connect](http://php.net/manual/de/function.sqlsrv-connect.php)

By Default it trys to establish a Connection with a Windows Auth. u can try the snipped below. If u have to use a defined WindowsUser to Login, try the Code from the documentation link above.

```
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName

// The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: One addition *In order to connect using Windows Authentication (on Windows) for Wamp/Xamp installations you should verify that the apache service is running under a user who can connect to SQL Server and not under a local user.* :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a part of code with connection string in which you provide instance name, login, password etc for PHP to connect to MS SQL. You can change connection string on your credentials from windows domain. But its acceptable for testing but not for production :)

Another way is to connect PHP to your AD and make user to enter login/pass from domain when they come on your site. For example it is simply done in IIS (I haven't work with domain auth on PHP that runs on Linux, but as I know LDAP can help [you](http://www.developer.com/open/article.php/3100951/Integrating-Active-Directory-with-PHP.htm)).